# didSelectRowAtIndex issue

Tags: iphone, xcode, didselectrowatindexpath

I have a `UITableView` in which I have added sections. When using `didSelectRowAtIndex` with `indexPath.row` I am not getting the correct value. Let's say I'm in section 2, then it starts the row index (indexPath.row) at 0 again and therefore I am getting the wrong index.

let's say the first array has 4 names: (0)50 street, (1)apple, (2)boy, & (3)cat. when you select anyone one it loads their correct detailview based on the index (0,1,2,3). however, when you go to search and type 'b' it narrows the table down to just (2)boy which is now in row 0. so when you select 50 street it loads boy from the original array.

Can anyone tell me how to fix this?
 I realize that it is possible to get the section index by `indexPath.section` but I can't figure out how to use this.

Comment: read some article about table view and use your mind with concentration.see this link for tableview tutorials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can calculate the "total row from top" by adding together the counts of the above sections, ie. `int j=0;for (int i=0;i<indexPath.section;i++) {j=j+[tableView numberOfRowsInSection:i];j=j+indexPath.Row;}`

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
if (indexPath.section == 0) // First section
{
//Do something
}
else if(indexPath.section == 1) // Second Section
{
//Do something 
}
}
```

Comment: Directory *aDirectory = [appDelegate.directories objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

the problem is i store my xml data in appdelegate and i create a Directory to store all my appDelegate(xml data) in it

then i display in _XMLDetailsView.aDirectory = aDirectory; 
where xmldetailsview directory values will be the same as the one in appDelegate.



however the array keeps starts from 0 instead of array(1) from section1 (the 2nd section)